# Where is goog.ui.menuBar provided?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library, plovr

I am learning how to make a menu bar using Google Closure libraries via this example.

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/menubar.html

However, when I try out the code in my own application, the Plovr compiler complains that no file provides `goog.ui.menuBar`. Is `goog.ui.menuBar` part of the Closure library or is there a plugin/extension that I must download to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy of Closure Library embedded in the February 8, 2012 release of plovr [hg revision  [4b3caf2b7d84](http://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/list)] uses [Closure Library revision 1559](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/detail?r=1559), which is dated February 2, 2012.

The menubar widget was introduced in [Closure Library revision 1947](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/detail?r=1947), dated June 4, 2012. Fortunately, you can download the latest version of the Closure Library and have plovr use the latest copy as follows:

#### plovr_config.json

```js
{
  "id": "myapp",
  "inputs": [
    "/home/my_project/js/myapp.js"
  ],
  "closure-library": "/path/to/closure-library/closure/goog",
  "mode": "ADVANCED",
  "level": "VERBOSE",
  "output-file": "/home/my_project/build/myapp.compiled.js"
}
```

> Where is goog.ui.menuBar provided?

`goog.ui.menuBar` is provided in the Closure Library in `closure/goog/ui/menubar.js`.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why `menuBar` is camel case though instead of Pascal case.

Comment: The reason `menuBar` is camel case instead of Pascal case is because there is no constructor named `MenuBar`. Instead of using a constructor, menu bar instances are created using the factory function `goog.ui.menuBar.create(opt_renderer, opt_domHelper)`.

Comment: An issue arises when I start adding in soy templates: Plovr claims that `soy` isn't provided anywhere. I subsequently added the `closure-templates` into my paths specification in config.js. However, Plovr then complains that `goog.debug.Error` is provided in 2 places. I might just download the file that provides `goog.ui.menuBar` and place it somewhere in my application directory instead of using another Closure installation...

Comment: See the last two comments on [plovr issue 55](http://code.google.com/p/plovr/issues/detail?id=55&q=closure%20library&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Reporter).